# Unexpected behaviour with FieldMask using dotnet core gRPC

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, grpc, grpc-dotnet

*From grpc/grpc-dotnet issue [#2097](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/2097)*

I am new to gRPC and I am not sure if I am implementing the FieldMask in the correct way.

Here are my messages definitions

```protobuf
// Events messages
message Event {
  // optional string id = 1 [deprecated = true];
  reserved 1;
  optional string name = 2;
  optional string description = 3;
 // ...
  optional string locationId = 21;
}

message UpdateEventRequest {
  string id = 1;
  Event event = 2;
  google.protobuf.FieldMask updateMask = 3;
}
```

and here is my csharp code

```cs
    public override async Task<EventResponse> UpdateEvent(UpdateEventRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {

        if (!_eventRepository.Exists(request.Id, out var evt) || evt is null)
        {
            throw new RpcException(new Status(StatusCode.NotFound, "Entity not found"));
        }
        
        var dto = evt.AdaptToDto();
    
        request.UpdateMask.Merge(request.Event, dto);

        await new EventValidator().ValidateAndThrowAsync(dto);

        evt = dto.AdaptToPoco(evt);
        var success = _eventRepository.UpdateEvent(evt);
        
        if (!success) throw new RpcException(new Status(StatusCode.NotFound, "Entity not updated."));

        return new EventResponse
        {
            Id = evt.Id,
            Event = dto
        };
    }
```

I am using .NET7 and Grpc.AspNetCore 2.52.0

when I try to update a field that has pascal-case  (like `locationId`) I face this wired error that occurs with some clients, when I send this request

```
{
    "id": "fd416fa0-5794-4bdc-be9e-1feece4f7cac",
    "event": {
        "locationId": "e3362b3b-2b8d-42cd-8c63-a5d9d9d46597"
    },
    "updateMask": "locationId"
}
```

in the path `locationId` get translated to `location_id`, where the merge fails.

[debug using string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmpYD.png)

but I am sending the following request

```
{
    "id": "fd416fa0-5794-4bdc-be9e-1feece4f7cac",
    "event": {
        "locationId": "e3362b3b-2b8d-42cd-8c63-a5d9d9d46597"
    },
    "updateMask": {
        "paths": [
            "locationId"
        ]
    }
}
```

the merge works but there is a warning inside the FieldMask

[debug using path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqlvg.png)

Did I do something wrong?
Is this the expected behavior, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using gRPC with JSON or the JSON you're sharing is your input to a manual testing tool like grpcurl? If the latter is true, what tool are you using?

Comment: @AlejandroLorefice I'm have tested with multiple tools Postman, Kreya, grpcui, JetBrains grpc plugin. Some of them have type checks and they don't allow me to use a different format, as an example Postman requires a path property with an array of strings, while kreya and grpcui require a string with comma-separated values.
By the way their behaviour is the same as the messages are transmitted in binary format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This comment](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/field_mask.proto#L182) on the source-code of `FieldMask` points that:

> Fields name in each path are converted to/from lower-camel naming conventions.

(a.k.a snake_case)

And in the examples you see they use full paths, not only the field they want to update but they also specify the message that contains it if any.

So, with your current JSON request I think you are technically requesting the update of a "root-level" field called `location_id`.

Consider using `location_id` as a field-name to align with the [style-guide](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/style/#message-field-names) or specify a `json_name` (assuming you are using `proto3`) like this:

```
message Event {
  // optional string id = 1 [deprecated = true];
  reserved 1;
  optional string name = 2;
  optional string description = 3;
  // ...
  optional string locationId = 21 [json_name = "location_id"];
}
```

And making the request like this should get it working:

```
{
    "id": "fd416fa0-5794-4bdc-be9e-1feece4f7cac",
    "event": {
        "locationId": "e3362b3b-2b8d-42cd-8c63-a5d9d9d46597"
    },
    "updateMask": {
        "paths": [
            "event.locationId"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed following the style-guide i was able to fix the issue.